# Best practice for checking data types at runtime objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, types

I have JSON data being provided to my application but unfortunatly it is not very well formed.  Sometimes I am getting String representations of numbers when I am expecting numbers.

For some reason some values may have a prefix of whitespace.

What is the best way to deal with this?  Currently I am forced to check the types via 'isKindOfClass' but having recently worked mainly on python applications this seems awkward.

Can anyone recommend a better way to do this?  I am fully aware that @try,@catch etc are not useful in this situation.

Thanks for your help guys,  I know this question is being flagged as subjective but I would appreciate some input!

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first: try *really* hard to get data which is well-formed. there are too many corner cases, and the process is computationally slow for any nontrivial json request - not to mention the wasted network bandwidth, parsing, etc.. it's a maintenance nightmare.

second: NSString and NSNumber share some convenience methods `intValue`, `doubleValue`. those will help in some of your cases.

third: if you have a *lot* of weird stuff, it's probably going to be best to create your own category methods. for example:

```
@interface NSString (MONEvilJSONSource)

- (int)ejs_intValue;
- (NSDate *)ejs_dateValue;
- (double)ejs_doubleValueForPropertyNamed_Millimeters;

@end

@interface NSNumber (MONEvilJSONSource)

- (int)ejs_intValue;
- (NSDate *)ejs_dateValue;

@end
```

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I am currently using 'intValue' on the objects descritpion method as a work around.  I was just hoping I had missed a more convenient method.  I managed to get the JSON provider to fix some of the issues with the JSON at source but I was hoping for a easy way for error recovery.